# difference in nuance between という、　といった

Tags: grammar

I know there are loads of uses for the former, but in the sentence

家族や結婚 といった　個人的な話であろうと、エンジニアリングや事業 といった仕事の話であろうと、向き合わないとなったらとことん向き合わないのが山田なのだ

can anyone explain the subtle difference that would be made if toiu was used instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel like the followings:

> ~~といった　＝　something such as ~~

AといったB：　B includes A.

> ~~という　＝ something that is ~~, something, in other words ~~

AというB：　A equals B.